# Setting the same secondary public IP on multiple servers

Tags: ip, failover, static-ip, netplan, systemd-networkd

The question concerns floating public IP's. I'm trying to set up a failover mechanism in the simplest way possible. Are there any hidden downsides to configuring the same secondary static public IP on multiple servers, while obviously only having it assigned to a single server at a time?
This way, no additional configuration steps would be needed at the time of failover.

To push this even further, one could be having multiple public IP's configured at the same time, PER server, on multiple servers, to handle a node failing inside a cluster with multiple active nodes.

Of course, I could always bring the IP up on the interface *after* it's been assigned through the provider, and then bring it down after it's unassigned, but this increases complexity, which I would like to avoid unless absolutely necessary.
Using netplan via networkd if relevant.

I did some testing with this setup, and I don't see any *immediate* drawbacks, but I'm wondering if there are any I haven't considered.

Comment: *"I could always bring the IP up on the interface after it's been assigned through the provider"* - it really depends on what kind of infrastructure you're talking about . AFAIK in many cloud environments a floating IP-address is more akin to NAT routing the traffic for that floating IP to an assigned interface on particular instance   and is there nothing in that instance that requires "activating" the floating IP when it is assigned nor deactivation when it is removed. That all only happens in virtual network layer of the cloud platform.